# letter by letter print messing up program

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

i recently added a 'letter by letter' string print to my code. for some reason it doesnt ask for an input before saying 'invalid input' why is this? it worked before and now it doesnt. i dont knwo what happened. is it something to do with the def() and it just goes sraight through? the letter by letter works but it just doesnt wait for an input. this is the code below

```
#this is the python turtle drawing challenge

import turtle
import math
import time
import sys

##################################################
def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.02)

def delay_input(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.02)

#################################################

def Main():

    delay_print("Welcome to the Python Turtle Drawing Challenge!")
    time.sleep(0.5)

    #variables
    distance = 0
    angle = 0
    leftRight = 0
    upDown = 0

    delay_print("\nYou will be asked to enter the distance, the angle, right or left and if the pen is up or down.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    delay_print("\nThe distance controls how far the pen goes.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    delay_print("\nThe angle is the angle at which the pen draws, compared to the previous angle it was at.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    delay_print("\nYou will also be asked if you want to go right or left, enter 'r' and 'l' accordingly.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    delay_print("\nYou will also be asked if you want to have the pen up or down, enter 'u' and 'd' accordingly.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    delay_print("\nTry to visualize how the drawing is going to work. Imagine the angles and the distances you will need. \nPress 'Alt' and 'Tab' to view your drawing at any time.\nGood Luck!")
    time.sleep(0.5)

    def subMain():
        upDown = delay_input("Is the pen up or down: ")
        time.sleep(1)
        if upDown == "u":
            turtle.up()
        elif upDown == "d":
            turtle.down()
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            delay_print("Invalid input, restart the program")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            Main()
            time.sleep(0.5)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        distance = int(delay_input("Enter the distance: "))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        angle = int(delay_input("Enter the angle: "))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        leftRight = delay_input("Left or Right: ")
        if leftRight == "l":
            turtle.left(angle)
            turtle.forward(distance)
        elif leftRight == "r":
            turtle.right(angle)
            turtle.forward(distance)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            delay_print("Invalid Input, restart the program")
            Main()
            time.sleep(0.5)
        fin = delay_input("is the drawing done? y/n: ")
        if fin == "y":
            time.sleep(0.5)
        elif fin == "n":
            time.sleep(0.5)
            subMain()
        else:
            delay_print("Invalid input, restart the program.")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        subMain()
    subMain()
    Main()

Main()
```

i tried to make it letter by letter and i was expecting to to still ask for input

Comment: "it worked before and now it doesnt." -- good opportunity to learn about version control, like git, so you can always go back to previous working versions (or do a poor man's version of backing up/snapshotting your files from time to time). See also [mcve]--you can probably remove a lot of code here and isolate the bug. Turtle seems irrelevant, it's just the text part that's failing. See also [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)--your function names are nonstandard and will be confusing to read and maintain. Recursion is also inappropriately used here and could result in a crash.

Comment: `delay_input()` is exactly the same as `delay_print()`. Both output to stdout and neither collect input. Both return None, which is why control goes to the "invalid input" branch. Maybe you meant to use the builtin `input()` rather than `delay_input()`? I don't understand how you'd delay input, exactly.

Comment: ah, what i did what i thought i could do was to just do the same as the delay print and make it ask for an input in the same manner. i am self taught so im just learning how all of this works. also what do you mean by recursion being used inappropriately? and what are the standard function names? thanks @ggorlen

Comment: If you use recursion, you need a stopping condition or it'll crash after ~1k loops. In this case, there is no such stopping condition, so the program will eventually crash. Once you fix it to accept input, it can still crash if the user gives bad input ~1k times. Unlikely, but still a brittle pattern and security hole. In general, avoid recursion in Python. See the PEP-8 link shared above regarding naming. You're right--you can print the prompt in a delayed manner, but the input still needs to be collected using `input()`, which is not a "delayed" thing and basically needs to be in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` is never called, so `delay_input()` is identical to `delay_print()`, in spite of the different name.

Adding `return input()` should give the desired behavior:

```py
def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.02)

def delay_input(s):
    delay_print(s)
    return input()
```

Notice that `delay_print(s)` is called inside `delay_input()` to reuse the existing code rather than repeat it.

As far as whether this is good UX or not is debatable. If I give invalid input, the whole program restarts rather than simply repeating the prompt, and I have to wait a good deal of time as the prints occur.

Turtle also has GUI-based text inputs that might be better alternatives: [textinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.textinput) and [numinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.numinput).

Always use Black to format code and follow [PEP-8 naming conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names): variables and functions are `snake_cased` and classes are `PascalCased`.

Unhandled conversion errors (e.g. `int()` calls based on user input) can crash this program.

Use loops for repetition rather than recursion. With recursion, if the user gives invalid input too many times, the program will crash.